# Is creating a reducer for each component that fetches data a good pattern?

Tags: redux

Imagine you have 2 components: TasksList and OverdueTasksList. The number of tasks is big, so you cannot load all tasks with 1 network request. This means that they both need to fetch data individually.

What's the best way to organize data with Redux in this case?

Here's my idea:

```
{
  tasks: {
    t1: {
      id: "t1",
      name: "Task 1",
    },

    // ...

  },

  tasksList: {
    isFetching: false,
    error: null,
    tasks: ["t1", ...]
  },

  overdueTasksList: {
    isFetching: false,
    error: null,
    tasks: ["t5", ...]
  }
}
```

This way, if you edit a task object from one component, it will be reflected in the other component as well.

What I don't like with this pattern is that you have to create a new reducer for every component that fetches data.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have 'overdue' as a property of task instead? therefore you could merge the 2 reducers into one:

```
const initialState = [];
tasks: function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
         case receiveOverduetask:
             return [...state, action.overdueTask];
         case receiveTask:
             return [...state, action.task];
         default:
             return state;
    }
}
```

You can still have the 2 separate requests, just make sure that they set the overdue property accordingly.

Comment: The problem is: where do you store isFetching and error for those 2 separate network requests?

Comment: Well, you would still have 2 loading  indicators just like you did before, one option could be something which looks like this loading {normal: true, overdue: false}.  The reducer would be a function that switches between the 2 actions receiveOverduetask and receiveTask and change the corresponding loading property.